# My accronyms don't appear in the document

Tags: acronyms, acro

I'm using `acro.sty` package and I have written my acronyms in `abbreviations.tex` file which is separated than `main.tex`, when I use `\ac{}` command e.g: `\ac{ai}`, the text appear in long version but not in short version, and the acronym don't appear in acronyms page.
But when I write my acronyms in `main.tex` file, everything appear normal.
here is my code for `main.tex`:

```
\documentclass[16pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage{acro}

\graphicspath{{ /images}}
\renewcommand*\thesection{\arabic{section}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}

\title{Takalem : A deep learning approach for Algerian sign language recognition}
\author{Fathi Abdelmalek}
\date{\today}



\begin{document}
    \makeatletter
    \input{includes/title.tex}
    \makeatother
    \pagenumbering{roman}
    \input{includes/dedication.tex}
    \input{includes/abbreviations.tex}
    \printacronyms
    \input{includes/abstract.tex}
    \tableofcontents
    \clearpage
    \listoffigures
    \clearpage
    \listoftables
    \clearpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}
    \clearpage
    \input{includes/part1.tex}
    \setcounter{chapter}{0}
    \input{includes/part2.tex}
    \newpage
    \bibliographystyle{abbrv}
    \bibliography{includes/references}
\end{document}
```

and here is `abbreviations.tex`:

```
\DeclareAcronym{ai}{
    short={AI},
    long={Artificial Intelligence},
}
\DeclareAcronym{ml}{
    short={ML},
    long={Machine Learning},
}
\DeclareAcronym{dl}{
    short={DL},
    long={Deep Learning},
}
\DeclareAcronym{nn}{
    short={NN},
    long={Neural Network}
}
\DeclareAcronym{cnn}{
    short={CNN},
    long={Convolutional Neural Network},
}
\DeclareAcronym{rnn}{
    short={RNN},
    long={Recurrent Neural Network},
}
```

this is example for a demo text i used:

```
\paragraph{}
\ac{ai} field is widely used those days, one of his major fields is \ac{ml}.
\paragraph{}
\ac{ml} is one of the major fields in \ac{ai}.
```

this code give me this output:

> Artificial Intelligence field is widely used those days, one of his major fields is Ma-
> chine Learning.
> Machine Learning is one of the major fields in Artificial Intelligence.

but when i write the acronyms in `main.tex`, this is the result which i want:

> Artificial Intelligence (AI) field is widely used those days, one of his major fields is Ma-
> chine Learning (ML).
> ML is one of the major fields in AI.

and they appear in acronyms page.

Comment: `hyperref` should be loaded after all other packages

Comment: Try and input your abbreviations file before `\begin{document}`, I am not sure how the package works but it might set things then that can't be changed after

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) All `\DeclareAcronym`s need to go in the preamble, you should be getting an error when you compile saying exactly that. Once you have an error, nothing in your document is guaranteed to be correct until that error is fixed.  If you move `\input{includes/abbreviations.tex}` to before `\begin{document}` does this work?